# "conda" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable

Tags: python, anaconda, tensorflow

Estoy instalando tensor flow para python 3.6. Lo estoy instalando con el metodo de Anaconda (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) al tratar de ejecutar este comando:

```
C:> conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5
```

Me sale este error:

```
"conda" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
```

Comment: Busca el lugar donde se ha instalado conda y colocalo en las variables del entorno.

Comment: Busca en el menú de inicio de windows “Anaconda console”. Te abrirá una interfaz de comandos como la de `cmd`, pero con las variables de entorno apropiadas para que el comando `conda` funcione (así como `python`, `pip`, etc.)

Answer (score 8):

No se compliquen:

PROBLEMA: Conda “conda” no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

CAUSA: Cuando instalaste anaconda, no activaste la casilla de agregar conda a las variables de entorno

SOLUCION (WINDOWS 10):

1. Abre el Anaconda Prompt (aparece en el menú inicio)
2. Escribe: where conda
   Te aparecerán varias direcciones de directorios, entre ellas el directorio raíz donde instalaste Anaconda y el segundo donde se encuentra la carpeta "Script"; cópialas en un block de notas
3. Abre el terminal de Windows en modo administrador
4. Escribe la siguiente información
   SETX PATH "%PATH%;*Dirección1*;*Dirección2*
   Donde
   Dirección1 es el primer directorio donde instalaste anaconda
   Dirección2 es el primer directorio donde está la carpeta Script
   La forma quedará muy parecido como sigue:
   **SETX PATH "%PATH%;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3**
5. Cierra el terminal.
   Para ver si quedó bien:
6. Abre nuevamente el terminal, y escribe conda --v
   Te debería aparecer la versión de Anaconda que tienes instalado.
   FIN

Answer (score 6):

Ubica la carpeta de Anaconda y pon la dirección en el `path`, en variables del sistema.

Por ejemplo mi carpeta esta ubicada en `C:\Anaconda3` y por tanto los scripts en `C:\Anaconda3\Scripts`,

- vas a información del pc,
- luego configuración avanzada del sistema,
- luego variables de entorno,
- en variables del sistema buscas PATH,
- ahí colocas las direcciones iniciando con punto y coma: `;C:\Anaconda3;C:\Anaconda3\Scripts`

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Bienvenido. Por favor, mira el [tour]

Answer (score 0):

Cuando instalaste anaconda, en un paso no seleccionaste la opción de añadir directamente anaconda a la dirección que te aparece por defecto en el símbolo del sistema. Posiblemente lo hiciste porque no era recomendado porque podía causar conflictos con otras aplicaciones, pero eso no es muy probable... realiza el paso #5 del siguiente link:

https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-python-on-windows-anaconda-c63c7c3d1444

Comment: los enlaces pueden no estar disponibles temporalmente (o definitivamente). incluye el "paso #5" para que no se pierda